# populate dropdown with table list

Tags: php, mysql

.hey guys how can i populate a dropdown list with the list of tables from a certain database?

```
$db = mysql_select_db('thepillar');
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<form method="post" id="try" action="pillar.php">';
echo 'Select Batch: ';
echo '<select name="batch" id="batch">';
echo '<option>';
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $tables = $r;
echo '<option>'.$tables.'</option>';
}
```

.i have tried the code above but the dropdown list is only filled with the word "Array" multiple times depending on how many tables are there in the database.

.help pls!

Comment: do a `print_r($tables)` inside the loop and take a look at what is retrived from the DB =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
$tables = $r;
```

with

```
$tables = $r['Tables_in_thepillar'];
```

also you got an extra `echo '<option>';`

above the loop

Answer (score 1):

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $r[0]."<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$tables` variable is an associative array. You need to specify which index of the array you want to output between the `<option>` tags.

```
echo '<option>'.$tables['TABLE_NAME'].'</option>';
```

See the `print_r` output for what the index name is.